# how can i manipulate the end output of a While Loop in PHP?

Tags: php, while-loop

I want to manipulate the **end output of a while loop**.

In this example, i am using number 5 in place of a variable.

```
<?php $i=1; while($i<=5)  {
echo "col-md-" . round(12/5) . "<br>";
$i++;
} ?>
```

giving output of

- col-md-2
- col-md-2
- col-md-2
- col-md-2
- col-md-2 
  ---> I want to show **4** here by applying the **below math** >>

  12-(5-1)*round(12/5)

Can you please help me with this. is it possible?
A help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Stop the loop one prior to what you want and echo the last item based on your calculations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to use a `for()` loop and end it one earlier and then output an extra column after...

```
$count = 5;   // Number of columns
for ( $i = 1; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
    echo "col-md-" . round(12/$count) . "<br>";
}
echo "col-md-" . (12-($count-1)*round(12/$count)) . "<br>";
```

Which gives...

```
col-md-2<br>col-md-2<br>col-md-2<br>col-md-2<br>col-md-4<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to check if the variable `$i` equals 5 before it gets incremented:

```
$i=1;
while($i<=5)  {
    echo "col-md-" . round(12/5) . "<br>";

    if ($i === 5) {
        echo "col-md-" . (12-(5-1)*round(12/5));
    }
    $i++;
}
```

If it is always at the end, you can just add it after the while loop:

```
echo "col-md-" .  (12-(5-1)*round(12/5));
```

Comment: I think (I am assuming) that they want `col-md-2` for the last one to be `col-md-4` so that it always adds up to 12 (probably bootstrap columns)

Comment: @NigelRen Now that you mention it, I think you are right.

Comment: @Thefourthbird your first answer is best. Because It's not always, only in the case of 5, 7, 8, 9, 10 and 11 which can't divide 12. Thank you and a big Thumbs up!

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code, which solved my issue.

```
$count = 1; // Number of columns 
for ( $i = 1; $i < $count; $i++ ) { 
  echo "col-md-" . floor(12/$count) . "<br>"; 
} 

if (($count == 5 || 7 || 8 || 9 || 10 || 11)) { 
 echo "col-md-" . (12-($count-1)*floor(12/$count)) . "<br>"; 
}
```

Thanks to @nigel and @thefourthbird.